# Installing Ubuntu - screen after log in is scrambled

Tags: system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.2.  The log in screen was perfect but after log in the screen went scrambled and blurred and that's as far as I can go.  I have tried to get in as administrator and as guest.  I have installed Ubuntu 64 bit and 32 bit but both times the same occurred. I have looked through all the similar problems on the questions page but none seem to be the same problem as I have.  I think that it might be something to do with the frequency being out of sync.  Can anyone help me with this?